# Как в javascrypt проверить наличие каждого символа из строки в другой строке?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить наличие символов из одной строки в другой строке?
Строка с символами.

```
var simbols = 'qwerty'
```

Строка в которой нужно проверить наличие.

```
var msg = 'Hello.'
```

Нужно проверить наличие каждого символа из строки simbols в строке msg и вернуть либо true либо false.
Я пытаюсь так:

```
for (i in simbols ){
    if (i in msg){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

И получаю ошибку.

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in Hello.
```

Как осуществить проверку корректным образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задание тогда это можно сделать вот так:

```js
const simbols = 'qwerty'
const msg = 'Hello.'

function checkSimbol(s1, s2) {
  for (let i = 0, n = s1.length; i < n; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0, n = s2.length; j < n; ++j) {
      if (s1[i] === s2[j]) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(checkSimbol(simbols, msg));
```